\NewDocumentEnvironment: inconsistent behaviour between \minipage and \center
Why do I get the Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup error for the pair of environment (AB) but not for (CD). I assume the difference boils down to how minipage is implemented... But is it possible to make it works also for the minipage?
\NewDocumentEnvironment{A}{}
{ \minipage{0.4\linewidth} bar }
{ \endminipage }

\NewDocumentEnvironment{B}{}
{ \endminipage\minipage{0.4\linewidth} foo }
{}

\NewDocumentCommand{\Foo}{}
{ \endminipage\minipage{0.4\linewidth} foo }

\NewDocumentEnvironment{C}{}
{ \center bar }
{ \endcenter }

\NewDocumentEnvironment{D}{}
{ \endcenter\center foo }
{}

\begin{document}
\begin{A} \begin{B} \end{B} \end{A} % -> fails
\begin{A} \Foo \end{A} % -> works
\begin{C} \begin{D} \end{D} \end{C} % -> works
\end{document}


Let's see. When you do \minipage{20pt}, at some point TeX will execute
\vbox\bgroup

(or \vtop or \vcenter, but it's irrelevant) expecting that the matching \egroup will be supplied by \endminipage.
If you open \begin{B}, you will have something like
\vbox\bgroup
<tokens from environment A>
<other tokens from \begin{B}>
\begingroup
<other tokens>
\egroup

and this is illegal, because you're in the middle of a group initiated by \begingroup which cannot end with \egroup. The \begingroup comes from \begin{B} and \egroup from \endminipage.
You're basically trying to do a complicated version of
{\begingroup}\endgroup

Indeed you get the error Extra } or missing \endgroup, because \bgroup and \egroup are mostly like { and } and TeX cannot really distinguish them in the case at hand, so it cannot say Extra \egroup.
There's no additional grouping with C and D, but this doesn't mean that their definitions are sensible.

Thanks for your answer... I updated my question as I realized that it works with NewDocumentCommand... It's wierd to me

@PinkFloyd That's a completely different situation, because there's not the additional grouping of environments.

Ok... I guess this black magic makes some sense!
